# What do these colors mean in the Server Timing API?

Tags: server-timing

I'm using the Server Timing API to debug some stuff and when I go to check them out in the "Timing" tab, I noticed most of them appear as red. I just assumed that was the color but then these two at the bottom are green. What do these colors mean, if anything? Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot of the Google Chrome debugger displaying the Network Tab, filtered by documents. The first item is selected showing info in the details pane. In the details pane, the Timing panel is open showing a list of Server-Timing headers that were sent with durations. Most of the durations appear as red but two appear as green. Details about the website have been redacted.]